# Don't generate BuildConfig - Gradle Kotlin DSL

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl, android-buildconfig

To disable generating `BuildConfig` with the Groovy DSL, one could do the following:

```
afterEvaluate {
    generateReleaseBuildConfig.enabled = false
    generateDebugBuildConfig.enabled = false
}
```

I am trying to find the equivalent when using Gradle's Kotlin DSL (build.gradle.kts). Anyone have any luck with this?

Answer (score 6):

If you have Android Studio 4.1 or greater you can use the [Build Features](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/4.1/com/android/build/api/dsl/BuildFeatures) Field to disable it per module.

```kotlin
android {
    ...

    buildFeatures {
        buildConfig = false
        resValues = false
    }
}
```

Comment: It's actually by default now on the latest gradle alpha version

Answer (score 2):

I ended up finding this to work as well:

```
android { ... }

tasks.withType<GenerateBuildConfig> {
    isEnabled = false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove BuildConfig from all variants by adding the following:

For library

```
android {
    ...

    // TODO replace with https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72050365 once released.
    libraryVariants.all {
        generateBuildConfigProvider?.get()?.enabled = false
    }
}
```

For application

```
android {
    ...

    // TODO replace with https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72050365 once released.
    applicationVariants.all {
        generateBuildConfigProvider?.get()?.enabled = false
    }
}
```

If you want to specify a build type , then:

```
libraryVariants
    .matching { it.buildType.name == "release"}
    .all {
        generateBuildConfigProvider?.get()?.enabled = false
    }
}
```